# Ubuntu syslog does not show previous days's logs

Tags: ubuntu, syslog

My Cron job is not running and i want to see what's problem in the syslog.

But that log is only showing current date only ,

Is there any way to keep logs for the last 10 days?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The logs are most likely being rotated by the logrotate process. Look in /etc/logrotate.conf. You should see something like this:

```
daily

rotate 1
```

Change that to:

```
daily

rotate 10
```

You could also do something like this to keep 4 weeks of logs:

```
weekly

rotate 4
```

Comment: i want to keep logs in one file only like in syslog for 1 month. how can i do that

Comment: Keeping more then a couple of days in a single file is a *really* bad idea for any server out on the internet, as there's a bunch of things that people can do to cause your server to log junk. Having logrotate keep logs longer is ok. `man logrotate` should help.

Answer (score 8):

Yesterdays log is /var/log/syslog.1.  They are rotated daily about 6 in the morning.  Previous days logs are syslog.2.gz... Use zless or zgrep to look at the compressed logs.

Data is likely in /var/log/messages as well.  This is rotated weekly, and has four weeks of old logs.